# Why does importing react pdf break my app from my npm library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, react-pdf

I am building a npm module: myLibrary, for my app: myMainApp.
I need to use react-pdf in myLibrary. In one of my component in myLibrary:

```
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
console.log(Document, Page);
```

I npm install myLibrary from myMainApp.
Error ouput:

```
Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined.
```

I tried removing all react-pdf code from myLibrary. Including that import { Document...} from 'react-pdf' line, rerun myMainApp, and no error.

Why does importing react-pdf in myLibrary break myMainApp?